# Google Maps: Apply Function to Multiple Shapes

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I need to draw multiple shapes on a map upon initialization and then add event listeners to see if the shapes have been modified or clicked on.

If I draw a single shape, the below code works properly:

```
// 1
var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
    id: '1',
    paths: [
        {lat: 38.56080094343725, lng: -121.74302101135254},
        {lat: 38.56106940317395, lng: -121.76750421524048},
        {lat: 38.57249479108347, lng: -121.76737546920776},
        {lat: 38.57244446296193, lng: -121.75782680511475},
        {lat: 38.57595057110021, lng: -121.75774097442627},
        {lat: 38.57583314441062, lng: -121.74778461456299}
    ],
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 1,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.1
});
polygon.setMap(map);

google.maps.event.addListener(polygon, 'click', function() {
    console.log(polygon.id);
});

google.maps.event.addListener(polygon.getPath(), "insert_at", getPath);
google.maps.event.addListener(polygon.getPath(), "remove_at", getPath);
google.maps.event.addListener(polygon.getPath(), "set_at", getPath);

function getPath() {
    var shapeCoords = '';
    for (var i =0; i < polygon.getPath().getLength(); i++) {
        var xy = polygon.getPath().getAt(i);
        shapeCoords += '{lat: ' + xy.lat() + ', lng: ' + xy.lng() + '},\n';
    }
    console.log(shapeCoords);
    console.log(polygon.id);
}
```

When I draw any additional shapes, I have to duplicate all of the click events and change the variable name (e.g. to `polygon2`).

```
// 2
var polygon2 = new google.maps.Polygon({
    id: '2',
    paths: [
        {lat: 38.56075060712497, lng: -121.76754713058472},
        {lat: 38.5605157038683, lng: -121.74289226531982},
        {lat: 38.55172305844243, lng: -121.7401671409607},
        {lat: 38.550665854985745, lng: -121.74636840820312},
        {lat: 38.54645366782474, lng: -121.745445728302},
        {lat: 38.54636975720739, lng: -121.74585342407227},
        {lat: 38.546302628643, lng: -121.74879312515259},
        {lat: 38.54655436043634, lng: -121.76778316497803}
    ],
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 1,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.1
});
polygon2.setMap(map);

google.maps.event.addListener(polygon2, 'click', function() {
    console.log(polygon2.id);
});

google.maps.event.addListener(polygon2.getPath(), "insert_at", getPath2);
google.maps.event.addListener(polygon2.getPath(), "remove_at", getPath2);
google.maps.event.addListener(polygon2.getPath(), "set_at", getPath2);

function getPath2() {
    var shapeCoords = '';
    for (var i =0; i < polygon2.getPath().getLength(); i++) {
        var xy = polygon2.getPath().getAt(i);
        shapeCoords += '{lat: ' + xy.lat() + ', lng: ' + xy.lng() + '},\n';
    }
    console.log(shapeCoords);
    console.log(polygon2.id);
}
```

Is there any way to use the same getPath function and/or event listeners so I don't need to duplicate the same code for each shape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to solve the problem the same way that was used in your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41434197/google-maps-applying-event-listeners).
Create a `createPolygon` function that takes the path, id, and any other options of the polygon you want configurable.  Use that to create the fixed polygons with its own internal version of `getPath` (so you have one instance of the function local to the polygon creation function, which has access to the closure on `polygon`, use the same function to create the polygons from the DrawingManager).

```
function createPolygon(id, poly) {
  var polygon;
  if (!(poly instanceof google.maps.Polygon)) {
    var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
      id: id,
      paths: poly,
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 1,
      fillColor: '#FF0000',
      fillOpacity: 0.1
    });
  } else {
    polygon = poly;
  }
  polygon.setMap(map);

  google.maps.event.addListener(polygon, 'click', function() {
    console.log(this.id + ' ' + this.getPath().getArray().toString());
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(polygon.getPath(), "insert_at", getPathCP);
  google.maps.event.addListener(polygon.getPath(), "remove_at", getPathCP);
  google.maps.event.addListener(polygon.getPath(), "set_at", getPathCP);

  function getPathCP() {
    var shapeCoords = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < polygon.getPath().getLength(); i++) {
      var xy = polygon.getPath().getAt(i);
      shapeCoords += '{lat: ' + xy.lat() + ', lng: ' + xy.lng() + '},\n';
    }
    console.log(shapeCoords);
    console.log(polygon.id);
  }
  return polygon;
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/tphm3qLm/4/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder;
var map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: -34.397,
      lng: 150.644
    },
    zoom: 8
  });
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  var shapeID = 1;

  function createPolygon(id, poly) {
      var polygon;
      if (!(poly instanceof google.maps.Polygon)) {
        var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
          id: id,
          paths: poly,
          strokeColor: '#FF0000',
          strokeOpacity: 0.8,
          strokeWeight: 1,
          fillColor: '#FF0000',
          fillOpacity: 0.1
        });
      } else {
        polygon = poly;
      }
      for (var i = 0; i < polygon.getPath().getLength(); i++) {
        bounds.extend(polygon.getPath().getAt(i));
      }
      polygon.setMap(map);

      google.maps.event.addListener(polygon, 'click', function() {
        console.log(this.id + ' ' + this.getPath().getArray().toString());
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(polygon.getPath(), "insert_at", getPathCP);
      google.maps.event.addListener(polygon.getPath(), "remove_at", getPathCP);
      google.maps.event.addListener(polygon.getPath(), "set_at", getPathCP);

      function getPathCP() {
        var shapeCoords = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < polygon.getPath().getLength(); i++) {
          var xy = polygon.getPath().getAt(i);
          shapeCoords += '{lat: ' + xy.lat() + ', lng: ' + xy.lng() + '},\n';
        }
        console.log(shapeCoords);
        console.log(polygon.id);
      }
      return polygon;
    }
    // 1
  var polygon1 = createPolygon(shapeID++, [{
    lat: 38.56080094343725,
    lng: -121.74302101135254
  }, {
    lat: 38.56106940317395,
    lng: -121.76750421524048
  }, {
    lat: 38.57249479108347,
    lng: -121.76737546920776
  }, {
    lat: 38.57244446296193,
    lng: -121.75782680511475
  }, {
    lat: 38.57595057110021,
    lng: -121.75774097442627
  }, {
    lat: 38.57583314441062,
    lng: -121.74778461456299
  }]);
  // 2
  var polygon2 = createPolygon(shapeID++, [{
    lat: 38.56075060712497,
    lng: -121.76754713058472
  }, {
    lat: 38.5605157038683,
    lng: -121.74289226531982
  }, {
    lat: 38.55172305844243,
    lng: -121.7401671409607
  }, {
    lat: 38.550665854985745,
    lng: -121.74636840820312
  }, {
    lat: 38.54645366782474,
    lng: -121.745445728302
  }, {
    lat: 38.54636975720739,
    lng: -121.74585342407227
  }, {
    lat: 38.546302628643,
    lng: -121.74879312515259
  }, {
    lat: 38.54655436043634,
    lng: -121.76778316497803
  }]);
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
  var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
    drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
    drawingControl: true,
    drawingControlOptions: {
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
      drawingModes: ['marker', 'circle', 'polygon', 'polyline', 'rectangle']
    },
    markerOptions: {
      icon: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png'
    },
    circleOptions: {
      fillColor: '#ffff00',
      fillOpacity: 1,
      strokeWeight: 5,
      clickable: false,
      editable: true,
      zIndex: 1
    }
  });
  drawingManager.setMap(map);

  google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'polygoncomplete', function(polygon) {
    drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);
    polygon.setOptions({
      id: shapeID,
      editable: true,
      draggable: true
    });
    createPolygon(shapeID++, polygon);
    shapeID++;
  });
}


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}
/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=drawing&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```